# Is it possible to only run one test class (that leverages PowerMock and Mockito)?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I am currently working on a project (with IntelliJ) with unit tests powered by PowerMock (for mocking `final` classes), and includes mocks using Mockito. The test suite takes a bit of time to run (via `mvn test`).

Is it possible to only run one test class (the one I'm working on)? It is a maven project, but I'm happy with any runner.

(If it helps with analogies/examples, I'm coming from a C#/NUnit background).

Comment: Your IDE should provide this functionality (right click the test method or test class). Surefire accepts a "-Dtest=SomeClass", see http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

Comment: I get a bunch of Mockito exceptions complaining about trying to mock this one `final` class. I will update my question to include Mockito.

Comment: Mockito cannot mock final classes (read the doc), this has nothing to do with how to run an unit test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Maven, see http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

If you're using Intellij Idea, position your cursor on the test method name and hit Ctrl+Shift+F10 (or right click on the method name and select the Run option)

Comment: Sorry just edited the question to include Mockito (not sure if that affects your answer).

Comment: Don't worry, the mocking framework does not matter here

Comment: Alright so, it doesn't work when I do it via IntelliJ directions you gave, but the `mvn -Dtest=testclass test` did. Does it matter that I have a parent `pom.xml`, and that I'm testing a child project using the child's `pom.xml`.

Comment: The POMs don't matter for IntelliJ in that case. Try the right-click way. Maybe you have some other key mappings. When you right-click on the test method name, you should have a "Run <your test method name>" context menu entry, possibly with a key binding next to it.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention this earlier.. The right-click way gives those errors (I'm using the VS keymap, so I couldn't get the Ctrl+Shift+F10 method to work).